# Distance between two alphabets in a string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string CNCCN and I need to find the index distance between the two Ns.

I know there are some ways to do this but involves writing many lines of code. Is there is a one-liner that could do this?

Comment: Show us the supposed "many lines of code" version first. Make an attempt. Also, probably not going to find a 1 liner for this, and not everything should be turned into one liners anyways.

Comment: You're first assuming that we know what a CNCCN means, and then asking for a library to do it for you.

Comment: Improve your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `str.index(char, [beg, end])` method to retrieve the position of a character inside a string. The method allows you to add a beginning and end position that you can use to check for the different occurrences.

Here the code:

```
s="CNCCN" 
dist = s.index('N', s.index('N') + 1) - s.index('N')
```

And its output:

```
print(dist) 
3
```

Using multiple lines you could avoid calling the `s.index(...)` method multiple times but you requested one-liner.

Comment: Thank you for this Cristian. You just made my life easy :)

Comment: @GaneshShahane Consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

string = 'CNCCN'

dist = np.diff([n for (n, e) in enumerate(string) if e == 'N'])[0]
print(dist)
```

Works for your specific example string...

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `string.find()` and `string.rfind()` methods:

```
str = 'CNCCN'
dist = str.rfind('N') - str.find('N')
print(dist)
# 3
```

`find()` finds the index starting left, `rfind()` does the same, but starts from the right.